# In Magento 2 is there a way to "force" kick-out all existing 'customer' sessions?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

Is there a way to "force" kick-out '**ALL**' existing '**CUSTOMER**' sessions in Magento-2? SO they have to re-login to the website?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using REDIS cache for session data, restart the REDIS service.

If you are using the file system for session data, remove all session data files in var/session folder.